# Responsive Table Bootstrap Hide Columns

Tags: java, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I would like to use responsive table in bootstrap but there's something wrong with my code that it's not working probably.

Here is My code:

```css
table { 
  width: 100%; 
  border-collapse: collapse; 
}
/* Zebra striping */
tr:nth-of-type(odd) { 
  background: #eee; 
}
th { 
  background: #333; 
  color: white; 
  font-weight: bold; 
}
td, th { 
  padding: 6px; 
  border: 1px solid #ccc; 
  text-align: left; 
}
@media 
only screen and (max-width: 760px),
(min-device-width: 768px) and (max-device-width: 1024px)  {

 /* Force table to not be like tables anymore */
 table, thead, tbody, th, td, tr { 
  display: block; 
 }
 
 /* Hide table headers (but not display: none;, for accessibility) */
 thead tr { 
  position: absolute;
  top: -9999px;
  left: -9999px;
 }
 
 tr { border: 1px solid #ccc; }
 
 td { 
  /* Behave  like a "row" */
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #eee; 
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 50%; 
 }
 
 td:before { 
  /* Now like a table header */
  position: absolute;
  /* Top/left values mimic padding */
  top: 6px;
  left: 6px;
  width: 45%; 
  padding-right: 10px; 
  white-space: nowrap;
 }
```

```html
<table class="table table-responsive">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>X Title</th>
      <th>Y Title</th>
      <th>Z Title</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
 <tr>
   <td> XXX </td>
   <td> YYY </td>
   <td> ZZZ </td>
 </tr>  
</tbody>
   </table>
```

There's something I don't know how to make it work like this following image only in Mobile or small screen sizes:

[Mobile View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X1dcw.png)

**

> **In mobile view I want to remove X TITLE, how to do it?**

**

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

```
Please follow the link

http://codepen.io/srees/pen/KNPPJy?editors=1100

Hope you got the answer
```

```css
body {
  padding:1.5em;
  background: #f5f5f5;
}

table {
  border: 1px #a39485 solid;
  font-size: .9em;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.25);
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-radius: 5px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

th {
  text-align: left;
}
  
thead {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #000;
  background: #d5d5d5;
}
  
 td, th {
  padding: 1em .5em;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
  
 td {
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.1);
  background: #fff;
}

a {
  color: #73685d;
}
  
 @media all and (max-width: 768px) {
    
  table, thead, tbody, th, td, tr {
    display: block;
  }
  
  th {
    text-align: right;
  }
  
  table {
    position: relative; 
    padding-bottom: 0;
    border: none;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
  }
  
  thead {
    float: left;
    white-space: nowrap;
  }
  
  tbody {
    overflow-x: auto;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    position: relative;
    white-space: nowrap;
  }
  
  tr {
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
  }
  
  th {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #f5f5f5;
  }
  
  td {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
  }
  
  
  }
```

```html
<table class="table table-responsive">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>X Title</th>
      <th>Y Title</th>
      <th>Z Title</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td> XXX </td>
      <td> YYY </td>
      <td> ZZZ </td>
    </tr> 
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: why do you need to use codepen links here, when you have the code snippet tool well with in the SO comment section toolbar. [<>]

Comment: I am very new to this stackoverflow. I have added code snippet too.

Comment: I understand you're new @sree :-) please explain your answer and you will get my vote ;-)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but as you can see in the provided image file, I want to remove X title in the mobile view and small screen sizes. even in your CSS code, still X title is there.